# How to find out whether a lat/long position resides within a Polygon?

Tags: postgis

I'm working on a system that stores latitude/longitude information of addresses in a PostGIS table. To store Lat/Long in geometry data type I'm using ST_GeometryFromText function.

For example the following function call gets the geometric value against the specified Long/Lat position:

```
 myPointGeo =  ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(40.758871 -73.985114)');
```

Similarly, I convert a Polygon into geometric representation as follows:

```
myPolygonGeo =  ST_GeometryFromText('POLYGON ((40.7566484549725 -73.9878561496734, 40.7556894646734 -73.9853026866913, 40.7545841705587 -73.9860537052154, 40.7548036054111 -73.9881458282471, 40.7559820394514 -73.9887895584106, 40.7566484549725 -73.9878561496734 ))')
```

I want to find out whether the above lat/long position resides within this Polygon or not. For this I'm using ST_Within function. But though 'myPointGeo' actually resides within the Polygon, ST_Within is returning false. I'm using ST_Within this way:

```
 St_Within(myPointGeo,myPolygonGeo)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Should I use some other function for this purpose?

Comment: Today I also landed up in same situation ; and the description present at this link helped me and is working good
http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html
Co-incidentally the examples there and the data type you using is same; so will be simple to replicate

Comment: Also note that the docs suggest to use ST_MakePoint, in general since it's faster - http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think ST_Intersects would work better, it returns a true or false on whether or not two geometries intersect.  So you'd want to do something like:

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(myPointGeo, myPolygonGeo);
```

or you can do:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id 
FROM pointTableName a, polygonTableName b 
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.myPointGeo, b.myPolygonGeo);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer